# Error 424 when using .Contains

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an error 424 "object required" when I use .Contains in VB.

See the following code :

```
Set oRst = oDB.OpenRecordset("Check Task Aircraft Listing", dbOpenDynaset)

Do While oRst.EOF = False
  Dim revNumber As String
  revNumber = oRst.Fields("CTAL_Rev")
  Dim aircraft As String
  aircraft = Me.aircraf
  Dim truc As Boolean
  truc = Revnumber.Contains(aircraft) <= error
  If truc = True Then
  ...
```

Someone know what's wrong ?

Comment: `Revnumber` - is type of string - `Dim revNumber As String` and doesn't contains method `Contains` - it's not vb.net, but vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Contains` is a VB.NET construct that VBA does not support. (VBA is *much* older than VB.NET.) The VBA equivalent would be

```
truc = (InStr(revNumber, aircraft) > 0)
```